# How to get output format JPEG using like source GeoTIFF (int16) in service WCS in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, web-service, jpg, wcs

I have GeoTIFF file (int16), and I publish the layer in Geoserver using like store in Geoserver my file, now I used WCS request builder to get JPEG-like output format and I get an error "No possible show the image because have errors". But If I convert my GeoTIFF file from Int16 to Byte, and I publish another layer in Geoserver with it I don't have any problem and I get JPEG in WCS, but in this case I get GeoTIFF (byte) too.

So, I want to get GeoTIFF (int16) and JPEG file by WCS service, so what kind of GeoTIFF I need like source? Or maybe I need any extension to get this?

This is my system:
- Ubuntu 14.
- apache-tomcat-8.5.32_2
- jdk1.8.0_181
- Geoserver 2.13.2
- native JAI and ImageIO extensions

Comment: can you add the exception from the log file after you turn up logging level to debug? and the gdalinfo output for the two input files

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as 16-bit JPEG http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2010/07/saving_16_bit_images_as_jpeg.html. The standard was enhanced in 2014 to support also 12-bits https://petapixel.com/2014/01/22/jpeg-standard-gets-boost-will-support-12-bit-color-depth-lossless-compression/

GDAL supports 8-bit and 12-bit JPEGs with libjpeg https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TIFF12BitJPEG but if you need 16 bit you must use some other compression.